Field is filled but I still get ValidationError
I want to create User using User.objects.create_user with fields of form Utilisateurs. Image and username fields are also used to populate model UserProfile.
views.py:
def sign_in(request):
    form=Utilisateur(request.GET)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=Utilisateur(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],
                                     password=form.cleaned_data["password"],
                                     first_name=form.cleaned_data["first_name"],
                                     last_name=form.cleaned_data["last_name"],
                                     email=form.cleaned_data["email"]
                                     )
            UserProfile.objects.create(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],profile_img=form.cleaned_data["profile_img"])
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())
    context={"form":form}
    return render(request,'signin.html',context)

models.py:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_img=models.ImageField(default="images/logo.png", upload_to="images/",blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now())

forms.py:
class Utilisateur(forms.Form):
    first_name=forms.CharField(min_length=4,max_length=15,label="Nom",widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"userclass"})))
    last_name = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=15,label="Prenom",widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"userclass"})))
    username=forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=15,label="Nom d'uttilisateur",widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"userclass"})))
    email=forms.EmailField(label="Email",widget=(forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class":"userclass"})))
    password=forms.CharField(label="Mot de passe",widget=(forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"userclass"})))
    profile_img = forms.ImageField(label="Image de Profile")
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    profile_img = forms.ImageField(label="Image de Profile", required=False)

Error:

{'profile_img': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]}

sign-in.html:
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Log_in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" >
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <h2 style="background-color: black; color: beige; padding: 5px; width:fit-content;">INSCRIVEZ-VOUS</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Log-in">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


In addition to all these, when I make migrations and then run "migrate", I get this message :
Your models in app(s): 'main_app' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
i've tried fake migrations, I've deleted the files from migrations directory except the init file, and made the migrations but still the same. I also deleted the table from the db and then ran sqlmigrate I don't know if this is related to my problem

related or not, i don't think you should make any changes to your database until your migration problem is solved

You need to pass request.FILES to your form.
